# Dynamic Pivot Columns with related tables in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am attempting to use a Pivot to dynamically create columns and am not getting the proper results I am looking for. I need to show all possible answers in its own column for each question (row), and there are multiple questions in a course. How can I generate each possible answer as a column name, and filter by courseId and the questionId for each row? The number of possible answers varies based on the question. Should this be done via cursor instead of pivot?

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @courseID float(24) = 1

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(questionID)
            FROM answers
            INNER JOIN questions ON questions.questionID = answers.questionID
            WHERE questions.courseId = @courseID
            order by 1 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

set @query = 'SELECT * from 
            (
                select Q.courseId, C.courseName, Q.question, Q.questionID, A.answer
                from questions Q 
                inner join courses C ON Q.courseId = C.courseId
                inner join answers A  ON A.questionID = Q.questionID
                where (Q.courseId = ''' + Str(@courseID) + ''')
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(answer)
                for questionId in (' + @cols + ')
            ) AS p'


execute(@query)
```

When running the above I am getting:

```
[1],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
```

As the generated columns which are the questionIds and not 'Answer 1, Answer 2 ... etc', and they are not displaying in order.

For the sake of brevity here are the related columns in the database tables:

**Courses**

```
courseId
```

**Questions**

```
questionId   question     courseId
```

**Answers**

```
AnswerId    questionId    answer
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide a many details on your table structure, but if you want the answers as the columns i.e. `Answer1`, `Answer2`, etc then you need to create the columns using `row_number()` against the number of answers per question similar to the following:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Answer'+cast(seq as varchar(10)))
            FROM
            (
                select row_number() over(partition by q.questionid
                                            order by a.answer) seq
                from answers a
                INNER JOIN questions q
                    ON q.questionID = a.questionID
                WHERE q.courseId = @courseID
            ) d
            group by seq
            order by seq
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');
```

This creates a sequence for each answer per question and then that sequence number is used to create the new columns names.  Then you will alter your PIVOT code to:

```
set @query = 'SELECT * 
            from 
            (
                select Q.courseId, C.className, Q.question, Q.questionID, A.answer,
                    ''Answer''+cast(row_number() over(partition by q.questionid
                                                        order by a.answer) as varchar(10)) seq
                from questions Q 
                inner join classes C
                    ON Q.courseId = C.courseId
                inner join answers A  
                    ON A.questionID = Q.questionID
                where (Q.courseId = ''' + Str(@courseID) + ''')
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(answer)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) AS p'


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail. I edited my question to include some of the table structure. In any case your example worked perfectly. Thank you!